# Check if below limits exist $\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \left( {\frac{{2{x^2}y - x{z^2}}}{{y^2 - xz}}} \right)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Check if below limits exist $$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \left( {\frac{{2{x^2}y - x{z^2}}}{{y^2 - xz}}} \right).$$
Is there any succession to prove that this limit is not zero?

Comment: This is your third question on the very same theme. Did you learn anything from the answers to the two previous questions? What did you try to attack this one?

Comment: If after several questions on the same verge you can't show some own effort to attack questions very closely related you're going to get downvoted.

Comment: @DonAntonio. Do you want to delete my post?

Comment: Not at all, @mathsalomon. What I'd like to see is some ideas from you how to attack this problem. It's understandable you're having a tough time tackling this stuff, but imo it isn't that after several questions on the same subject you don't show some ideas to solve *your* problem that you may have received from the answers you got. It's just like you're expecting your homework solved for you by others...

Comment: *Et voilà !* Everything is in place for a fourth question, completey similar to the previous ones, with no hint whatsoever of what the OP tried.

Comment: @Teddy. OK, I'll take that into account, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the sequence $x_n = z_n = \frac{1}{n}$, and $y_n = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}$, you get
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{2}{n^4}}{\frac{2}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^4}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
You can easily find a sequence for which the limit is $0$, and hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: Many thanks! is good!

Comment: @Teddy  is this unique way to solve such problem?

Comment: @Teddy. What criteria do you use to calculate the sequence?

Comment: @dato The function is not defined along the line $x=y=z$. I found that many times it pays to check a sequence which approaches the limit point, along a curve that is "close" to the curve where the function is undefined.

Comment: @Teddy. Very ingenious, good point.

Comment: wonderful solution. +1